# Is there a way to put the image just next to the paragraph using flex properties?

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I tried setting `justify-content` to `space-between` as but that didn't work either.

The image just seems to come just below the paragraph.
But I want it to look like this.
[image: I want it to look like this]

Home.jsx

```
import '../App.css';
import './Home.css';
import pic from './portfolio-image.jpeg';
import React, { Component } from 'react';



function Home(){
    return(
        <div className='safe-area'>
            <div id = 'home-container'>

                <div id = 'home-text-container'>
                    <div id='home-head'>
                        Hi, I'm <Name>.
                    </div>

                    <div id = 'home-body'>
                        I am passionate about software and web development. I like solve interesting and new problems through my expertise in coding.
                        I like to work with React, Firebase, MongoDB, Express, Python and more.
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div id = 'image-social-container'>
                    <img src= {pic} />
                    
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


export default Home;
```

Home.css

```
#home-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    align-content: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
    height: 75vh;
    margin-left: 2cm;
    margin-right: 2cm;

    background-color: black;
}

#home-text-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

    width: 50%;
    line-height: 40px;
}


#home-head{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 210%;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #b8fff1;
}

#home-body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 140%;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: #b8fff1;
}

#image-social-container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}


#image-social-container img{
    width: 15%;
    border-radius: 10%;

    align-self: flex-end;
}
```

Comment: if you have a layout based on grid placement, you probably want to [use CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) instead of flexbox.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly your layout goal is, but I'd start with taking out the `width: 15%;` line from your `img` styling. See [this CodePen example](https://codepen.io/baadaa/pen/MWOmRgm) I prepped for you.

#### A few CSS concerns:

- **Too many IDs**. Consider replacing `id`s with `class`es. Actually, you could just rely on basic cascading rules to avoid unnecessary `id`/`class` pieces
- **Mixing different measurement units (e.g. `cm`, `vh`, `%`, and `px`)**: I'd suggest you understand what each measurement actually work before mixing and matching them. For instance, `%` value can mean a few different things depending on what it's used for and what the element's parent is.

Comment: Note I didn't fix anything else in the CodePen example, except taking out the `width: 15%` line—just to show how it could start to work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use **flex-direction: column** on the container.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).